# Need code for Inverse Error Function in Python/Spark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am aware of libraries such as scipy,symph and pyerf which provide erfinv function.
However I am looking for the code in a pure mathematical formula.
Need to replace erfinv in this formula(math.sqrt(2) * erfinv(x*2-1))

Comment: Maybe sympy and not symph?

Comment: Do you need to replace `erfinv(x)` with some other expression?

Comment: n=math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*0.008-1)
print(n) -->-2.4089155458154616

Comment: n=math.sqrt(2)*erfinv(2*0.008-1)
print(n) -->-2.4089155458154616......need to replace erfinv function in this equation

Answer (score 0):

Using the Rational Chebyshev Approximations for the
Inverse of the Error Function you may be able to implement it although there a several edge cases so that solution may be extremely complicated; I simplified the C code that scipy uses to calculate erfinv to showcase how a simpler python implementation may look like.

```
import math

def erfinv(x):
    lower_b = -1
    upper_b = 1

    threshold = pow(1,-7)

    if -threshold < x && x < threshold:
        #using a simpler Taylor expansion for small values        
        return x / (2/sqrt(math.pi))
    
    elif lower_b < x && x < upper_b:
        #requires Gaussian cum distribution implementations (requires indefinite integration)
        return Gaussian_cumulative_distribution_function(0.5 * (x+1)) * (1/sqrt(2))

    elif x == lower_b:
        #show negative infinity, somehow
        pass
    
    elif y == domain_ub:
       #show positive infinity, somehow
        pass
    
    else:
        #unique solution cannot be guaranteed outside of the established domain
        raise Exception('Error')
```

All of this considered, I would say that when you are faced with numeric calculations that are this complex you are probably best served by libraries like scipy in most cases; thus I would recommend this approach to anybody wanting to perform the same computation.

The simplest solution I could come up with requires numerical indefinite integration, and a solution using the approximation I mentioned at the start of this answer would require rational functions of different degrees with many coefficients (which isn't necessarily hard to implement but probably extremely time consuming)

A couple research papers that I read while writing this answer and may guide you if you decide on a more 'pure' solution:

[Rational Chebyshev Approximations for the
Inverse of the Error Function](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-136/S0025-5718-1976-0421040-7/)

[Approximations to inverse error functions](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4630740)